# Does this count as "Sea kayaking"?

Tags: insurance, norway, canoeing-and-kayaking

I am going on a cruise to the Fjords where I am going kayaking on the Nærøyfjord.

[image: location]

(the pin is where I will be kayaking)

The insurer (Post Office) says I need extra cover for "sea kayaking". Does this count as "sea kayaking". Should I get the extra cover just in case?

Comment: Um, the fjord is part of the sea, so how could it *not* be?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I suspect that's what they're asking.  Sometimes it's unclear to people eg lakes with egresses into the sea, estuaries and the like.

Comment: indeed you can get freshwater fjords, which I didn't know until now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fjord.  But in this case I'd agree, it appears oceanic.

Comment: Although https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A6r%C3%B8yfjord seems to indicate a river flows down it....so ... could argue either way

Comment: @MarkMayo: As far as I can see the Wikipedia page just says a river flows _into_ the fjord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see the confusion, as even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A6r%C3%B8yfjord) talks about the river flowing through it, and indeed, some fjords are freshwater.

Certainly, at least the photos of [one kayak company](https://www.freedomwanderers.com/blogs/kayaking-naeroyfjord) indicates it's river-based, primarily.

However, another literally describes [sea kayaking in the fjord](https://nordicventures.com/).

Ultimately, it's going to come down to whether or not you have an argument with your insurance company. So it's best to contact them, ask if THEY consider it sea kayaking, and regardless of the answer, get it in writing. That was you know where you stand, regardless.